# How can I get the last key in Firebase Android?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to get the last key of the book node and incremented by a his value++.

I tried this:

```
    myRefVal=databaseBook.getReference("books");
    Query lastQuery = myRefVal.limitToLast(1);

    lastQuery.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            idBook = dataSnapshot.getKey();
            int counter = 1;
            counter = counter + 1;
            idBook = idBook + counter;
        }
        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
```

[image]

At beginning I had justBook 1 ,after click on addbook button I had book2 but when I tried to add a 3rd time a book the previous book2 values crash and the new ones tackes places on Book2.

I'm using `idBook` to create node book in Firebase Database

```
myRefBook.child(idBook).setValue(bookInfos);
```

Comment: Have you a solution ? @AL.

Comment: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/lists-of-data#read_and_write_lists

Answer (score -1):

Instead of using methods to create keys, I used the push method of firebase that allows you to create random key Node:

```
private void createBook(String nom_livre,String cat_selected, String type_annonce_selected ) {

    bookInfos=new Book(nom_livre,cat_selected,type_annonce_selected);

        myRefBook.push().setValue(bookInfos);

}
```

And I used `orderByKey()` and `dataSnap.getKey()` to get the last key displayed:

```
  ref.orderByKey().limitToFirst(2).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                     List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
                    for (DataSnapshot dataSnap : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {

                        Book valueBook = dataSnap.getValue(Book.class);
                        keyId = dataSnap.getKey();

                        String titreLivreToDisplay = valueBook.getNom_livre();
                        String descLivreToDisplay = valueBook.getDesc_livre();

                       //Do what you want with the key Node

                  }}  });
```